# How can we restrict internal requests to a service in Istio?

Tags: kubernetes, istio

For example I have got a Service called `Data`. That selects a `data pod` which basically returns `"Hello-World"`.

But I have also got three more Services that connects to Data Service to get that `"Hello-World"`

1. ServiceOne
2. ServiceTwo
3. ServiceThree

Now the question is: is there any way I can restrict `ServiceThree` to access `Data` Service?

Well  I tried using `http.match.sourceLabels` in `VirtualService` but that does not restrict.

One thing that worked for me is **`Simple Denials`** in Istio, but that's not what I wanted. You can find information about it on : https://istio.io/docs/tasks/policy-enforcement/denial-and-list/

I am basically looking for a way where you add some configuration in your `VirtualService` which allows only certain Services to access the host service?

Comment: You should be looking at https://istio.io/docs/tasks/security/authorization/

Comment: 1.What does You mean sourceLabls dont work, any errors here or it just didn't work? 2.Can you provide yamls  so it would be easier to make reproduction of your problem and prepare example for You? 3.What You think about @Tummala Dhanvi link? I think it might work.

Comment: @TummalaDhanvi Thanks, I think that should work, i ll have a go and let you know.